# GraphicsPath eliminate text border

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, gdi+

I'm using the `GraphicsPath` object to draw text in a rectangle. The rectangle is larger than the text, and I want to draw the text in any of the rectangle's corners, and also at the center of its edges.

The problem I have is that when I draw the path, a border is being left around the source rectangle. I want to be able to eliminate that border and make the text touch its bounding rectangle.

Here is the code I have:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var g = e.Graphics;
    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

    Rectangle textRect = new Rectangle(100, 100, 150, 150);
    Font f = new Font("Arial", 16);
    float emSize = f.Height * f.FontFamily.GetCellAscent(f.Style) /
               f.FontFamily.GetEmHeight(f.Style);

    foreach (StringAlignment lineAlignment in Enum.GetValues(typeof(StringAlignment)))
    {
        foreach (StringAlignment alignment in Enum.GetValues(typeof(StringAlignment)))
        {
            StringFormat sf = new StringFormat() { LineAlignment = lineAlignment, Alignment = alignment };
            using (GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath())
            {
                gp.AddString("txt", f.FontFamily, (int)f.Style, emSize, textRect, sf);
                RectangleF bounds = gp.GetBounds();
                g.FillPath(Brushes.Black, gp);
                g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, Rectangle.Round(bounds));
            }
        }
    }          

    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, textRect);
}
```

And here is the result:

[image: Result]

Basically, I want the red rectangles (and the text they contain) to touch the blue rectangle, and to eliminate the border between them. Also, I need to use the `GraphicsPath` and not `DrawString`.

Comment: Try using `sf = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericTypographic)` to get rid of the left and right margins.  I don't know about the top and bottom margins.  Different problem, I think.

Comment: You are asking for a lot of trouble.  Glyph overhang, and the vertical space for descenders and diacritics are tricky typography details.  You got the GraphicsPath.Bounds, use Graphics.TranslateTransform() to move it where you want it.

Comment: @HansPassant Now I understand that the space is there for descendants and diacritics. If you type out an answer, I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a helper method to calculate the offset of the rectangles and translate the text before drawing it. Here is the method I wrote:

```
private PointF FixAlignment(RectangleF parentRect, RectangleF childRect,
    StringAlignment lineAlignment, StringAlignment alignment)
{
    float xOffset = 0;
    float yOffset = 0;

    switch (lineAlignment)
    {
        case StringAlignment.Near:
            yOffset = parentRect.Top - childRect.Top;
            break;
        case StringAlignment.Far:
            yOffset = parentRect.Bottom - childRect.Bottom;
            break;
    }

    switch (alignment)
    {
        case StringAlignment.Near:
            xOffset = parentRect.Left - childRect.Left;
            break;
        case StringAlignment.Far:
            xOffset = parentRect.Right - childRect.Right;
            break;
    }

    return new PointF(xOffset, yOffset);
}
```

I used it in the `Form1_Paint` method like this:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var g = e.Graphics;
    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

    Rectangle textRect = new Rectangle(100, 100, 150, 150);
    Font f = new Font("Arial", 16);
    float emSize = f.Height * f.FontFamily.GetCellAscent(f.Style) /
               f.FontFamily.GetEmHeight(f.Style);

    foreach (StringAlignment lineAlignment in Enum.GetValues(typeof(StringAlignment)))
    {
        foreach (StringAlignment alignment in Enum.GetValues(typeof(StringAlignment)))
        {
            StringFormat sf = new StringFormat() { LineAlignment = lineAlignment, Alignment = alignment };
            using (GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath())
            {
                gp.AddString("txt", f.FontFamily, (int)f.Style, emSize, textRect, sf);
                RectangleF bounds = gp.GetBounds();

                // Calculate the rectangle offset
                PointF offset = FixAlignment(textRect, bounds, lineAlignment, alignment);
                // Translate using the offset
                g.TranslateTransform(offset.X, offset.Y);
                g.FillPath(Brushes.Black, gp);
                g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, Rectangle.Round(bounds));

                // Translate back to the original location
                g.TranslateTransform(-offset.X, -offset.Y);
            }
        }
    }

    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, textRect);
}
```

Here is the result:

[image: Result]